# Why did some of the fonts and colors of some of the items on my Google sheets toolbar change?

Tags: google-sheets

Today when I created a new Google sheet a number of the items on the toolbar turned white and became invisible:

[image]

I have a couple of Google accounts and this seems to have only happened with one particular account.  I can't find any setting that I might have changed to inadvertently cause this.  I opened and reopened Chrome and even restarted my Mac, but can't fix the issue.

Answer (score 1):

There is no such option that you can change GUI font color with. if you are sure the issue is not caused by you (tampering with code, running scripts, addons or extensions, etc.) then hit that share button and send them feedback to fix it for you:

[image]